# How to connect to Azure Files (preview) share?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I enabled Azure Files preview.

I follow this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx

I created new storage account called loremipsum. Using powershell, I created new storage share called loremipsum-01. Called `New-AzureStorageDirectory` command to test create directory. It succeeded.

I went to command prompt and called this command:

```
net use z: \\loremipsum.file.core.windows.net\loremipsum-01 /u:loremipsum accesskey==
```

Result:
System error 64.
Network name is undefined.

**How should I connect to this share, so I can use it as mapped folder in explorer?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you're trying to connect to Azure File Service share from your local computer. Please note that this is not possible today. You can only mount a share from the VM/Web or Worker Role running in the same region. From the blog post link above (Step 4: Use File Share):

> Once your share is created, it can be accessed via the SMB or REST
>   protocol from **any Azure node (VM/Worker/Web role) hosted in the same
>   region as the storage account hosting the share**.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can access Azure file share from a windows machine by using    [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/). It is very easy to Install and use. If    you want to mount It on any VM and want to use, then you can use [How    to mount wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows)